# Do I need CDN if I am target to small region?

Tags: cdn

I have website which is targeting to small geografical area, the bigest CDN companies don't even have CDN servers close to this area. I am wondering will I get any benefit to use CDN, becouse main server will be closer geograficaly?

Comment: Looks to me like you've pretty much answered your own question: if the CDN's USP - more servers, closer to users - isn't true for you, then they're of no business use to you except to provide redundancy.

Answer (score 4):

Quite possibly you might want one anyway.

They tend to be good at not being vulnerable to DDoS, and make it more difficult to find and attack your real servers in many cases.

Not all of the Internet's topology is geographic.  If you want to use one, select one which is well-peered to ISPs which serve your target market.

Comment: For example my target country is New Zealand and closest CDN server is in Sydney thousands miles away.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same for me and I use CDN because i can't provide enough hitrate on my servers, i'd like focus on development, not on server management.